# Complexity of checking value in a list while creating list

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

What is the worst case time complexity of the following code:

```
temp_lst = [(1, "one"), (2, "two"), (3, "three")]

if 5 not in [i[0] for i in temp_lst]:
    print("5 is not here")
```

My understanding is that it's **O(n^2)** because you're both building a list while searching this list, so equivalent would be some sort of for loop inside another for loop.

Comment: You're making one new list, which is O(n), and looking through it, which is O(n). So overall it's O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming *n* means the length of `temp_lst`, then this code has a time complexity of O(*n*).

The list comprehension `[i[0] for i in temp_list]` is equivalent to the following loop, which is clearly O(*n*):

```py
result = []
for i in temp_lst:
    result.append(i[0])
```

The resulting list has the same length, *n*, so the expression `5 not in ...`, which is implemented as a [linear search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search), also takes O(*n*) time.

The list comprehension and the linear search are done one after the other, so we should add, not multiply: O(*n*) + O(*n*) = O(*n*).

Answer (score 2):

This is linear--build the lookup list once and traverse it once. O(2n) reduces to O(n).

Having said that, this appears to be a problematic design that I'd consider to be an antipattern, absent of any further information. If the tuples are indeed sequentially numbered and unique, then this structure makes far more sense as

```
temp_lst = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Now, we can simply say `if 5 < len(temp_lst)` and we have O(1) lookup time. Not only that, the code is simpler and there is no redundant information. If you need 1-indexing, either add a `None` to the front of the list or subtract 1 from all your lookups.

If the numbers aren't sequential and would leave holes in the list, then a `dict` is likely the appropriate structure:

```
users = {"51232": "bob", "12342": "amy", "17652": "carol"}
```

Again, we have O(1) lookup time when searching by id, `"51232" in users`.